# Filter and search in DataTable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

I have a datatable of tasks, which includes a column of role(hidden column) of current user. I want to display the content based on the role selected by the user. I can use either - search | Filter API of datatable. But which one would suit this scenario the most? In a way, both these API do the same thing from user perspective.

Roles can be -  creator, assigned or interested.

Comment: Is this a programming question (i.e. implementation in a Rails controller) or regarding user interface design? For the latter, since the operation is only applicable to a specific column, I'd use the filter API for that.

Comment: Its for the front end. Thanks for your suggestion but i have a query - Since my roles column is hidden, will filter API still work for it ?

Comment: The datatable shows the filter below the respective column. So if the column is hidden it won't be possible to filter for it. I think I might have misunderstood the question. Can you clarify?